# AJAX not working when run in Netbeans

Tags: javascript, ajax, netbeans-7

I am learning AJAX in class and have run into an issue trying to get AJAX to work. The problem I am having is the onKeyUp event of a html text box wont run any Javascript function if Netbeans runs the file. The onKeyUp event works perfectly fine if you just view the page, but that wont let me use the servlet that contains the Java code I want to use with AJAX.

Is there a setting in Netbeans that could be causing this problem?

Note:
Trying to call alert("test"); from the onKeyUp does not work when run. It works if viewed.

Answer (score 0):

It's not problem with Netbeans, check in your code and make sure

if `onKeyUp` event works fine then check if you can request a servlet may be you haven't correctly given path to servlet as mentioned in web.xml

Comment: The thing is, the servlet works fine on its own. Also trying to call alert("test"); from the onKeyUp does not work when run. It works if viewed